# SAMLRequest 403 Access denied in css link tag

Tags: html, css, spring, jsp, spring-security

I have an issue with adding link tag in my jsp page in Spring MVC application.

This jsp page is used to handle "Access Denied" after making SAMLRequest. But some how my link tag is getting SAMLRequest instead of CSS text in jsp. Can some one help me in this issue?

**My JSP**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/temp.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="forbidden">
        <div class="repeat-image">
            <div class="main-image image403">
                <div class="text-block">
                    <p class="status">403</p>
                    <p class="title">Access Denied</p>
                    <p class="message">You currently do not have permission to access this page.  Want access?</p>

                    <div class="instructions">
                        Instructions to request via Self Service UAA<br />
                        <ul>
                            <li>In SSUAA --> Search for "Access"</li>
                            <li>Click "Next" to confirm requests</li>
                        </ul>
                        You will receive an email confirmation and status updates for your request
                    </div>
                    <div class="message">
                        Go ahead and request it <a href="url" target="_blank">here &raquo; </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Firebug HTML Tab:**

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" href="css/temp.css" rel="stylesheet">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>HTTP Post Binding (Request)</TITLE></HEAD><BODY Onload="document.forms[0].submit()"><FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="/idp/SSO.saml2"><INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="SAMLRequest" VALUE="PHNhbWxwOkF1dGhuUmVxdWVzdCB4bWxuczpzYW1scD0idXJuOm9hc2lzOm5hbWVzOnRjOlNBTUw6Mi4wOnBm5hbWVpZC1mb3JtYXQ6dHJhbnNpZW50IiBBbGxvd0NyZWF0ZT0idHJ1ZSIvPjwvc2FtbHA6QXV0aG5SZXF1ZXN0Pg=="/><INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="RelayState" VALUE="https://localhost:8080/"/></FORM></BODY></HTML>
</link>
</head>
<body>
</html>
```

**Directory Structure:**
[image]

**Security Portion:**

```
<security:http pattern="/css/**" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/images/**" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/403" security="none" /> 

<security:http entry-point-ref="entryPoint"
    use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
        access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:custom-filter position="CAS_FILTER"
        ref="authenticationFilter" />
    <security:logout logout-url="/signout"
        logout-success-url="/" />
    <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
</security:http>

<bean id="authenticationFilter"
    class="com.espn.ese.ais.vod.ams.security.picketlink.PicketLinkAuthenticationFilter"
    lazy-init="true">
    <constructor-arg value="${picketlink.filter.processes.url}" />
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="${picketlink.service.url}" />
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
            <constructor-arg value="/403" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider
        ref="authenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="authenticationProvider"
    class="com.espn.ese.ais.vod.ams.security.picketlink.PicketLinkAuthenticationProvider"
    lazy-init="true">
    <property name="authenticationUserDetailsService">
        <bean
            class="com.espn.ese.ais.vod.ams.security.picketlink.PicketLinkAuthenticationUserDetailsService">
            <constructor-arg ref="userDetailsService" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="userDetailsService"
    class="com.espn.ese.ais.vod.ams.security.TestUserDetailsService"
    lazy-init="true" />
```

**Page Not found:**

```
2016-07-28 10:19:18,023 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/{contextroot}/css/temp.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-web'
```

Comment: Please post the directory structure of your css/jsp and the portion of your security configuration that defines how filters are applied and which directories are permitted.

Comment: @blur0224 - I have updated my post as per your comment. Thank you!

Comment: Something in the SAML security configuration is protecting the URL erroneously.   If you're able, can you post the complete SAML security config?  Also, turn your spring logging to debug and post the block of log output corresponding when the page is loaded.  There should be some output showing the request being redirected.

Comment: Yes, i have updated. @blur0224

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found the solution for above issue. I was missing `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` in my spring-web-servlet.xml

Thanks @bluro224 for your time.